# Mysql special character

Tags: mysql, sql

---

I have a problem in mysql,

How can I store users' nickname like this: "" in a database?

[image: screenshot] 
Because for the moment it gives me: "????????????????????" in the table and I really need the real username of all users so I can rank them with the correct nicknames
Thank you!

Comment: If you're getting `?` you're having UTF-8 issues. Ensure your table is `utf8mb4` as well as *all* connection settings.

Comment: Yes I do, but doesn't work

Comment: This is likely the UTF-8 "all the way through" problem.

Comment: So could I fix it?

Comment: Yes, by setting UTF-8 all the way through as `utf8mb4`.

Comment: I've already set it to utf8mb4 but it doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

Store the name with HTML tags:

""  = `<b><i>Morcyyyy</i></b>`

Comment: How does this solve any problems? It won't help with , and allowing arbitrary HTML injection in a username is how you XSS yourself.

Comment: Good point thanks for pointing that out